# How to get position of all elements in the div

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Ok sow i have list of objects the evry object this the div that contains info and picture of product (div is the product with all info) this is the code

```
id="insert-zone" class="ui-droppable ui-sortable">
<div class="item-container cart-item">
<img border="0" src="http://www.myengravedjewelry.com/images/products/medium_101-01-004-02.jpg" alt="">
<div id="Item_Logo" class="item-header><asp:hyperlink style=" imageurl="images/Logo.png" navigateurl="EcomAdminCenter.aspx" runat="server" 0'="" z-index:=""> </div>
<div class="item-body">
<div class="item-footer"></div>
</div>
<div class="item-container cart-item">
<div class="item-container cart-item">
<div class="item-container cart-item">
<div class="item-container cart-item">
<div class="item-container cart-item">
<div class="item-container cart-item">
<div class="item-container cart-item">
</ol>
```

this all divs/products ar sorted 4 in the row and x columns 
Problem:
When i change the order of divs/product (by ui drag and drop) and press "Save changes" i need to go throw all divs/product and save they position (x,y) after this i will sort by (x,y) sow i can say who is in the first place and 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.... and next.
I other words i need to save every position of all element that i the "cart-item" and put it in arr and then sort by (x,y).

After long research i found answer

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-item");

for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++){

console.log("x->",elements[i].offsetLeft,"y-->",elements[i].offsetTop,"ProductId-->",elements[i].textContent.substring(9,14));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-item");

for(i=0;i

console.log("x->",elements[i].offsetLeft,"y-->",elements[i].offsetTop,"ProductId-->",elements[i].textContent.substring(9,14));